# Common framework for POST over HTTP and SOAP over HTTP webservices

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, http-post, jax-rs

We have a bunch of services that support Post over HTTP similar to normal web app processing where in a form is sent via post and also SOAP over HTTP via the IBM soap gateway, our design is slightly messy today as we had combined a lot of processing logic tied to the transport protocol where we parse the XML contents via DOM parser and have seperate classes for Post and SOAP over HTTP, etc. We want to streamline this such that we have a common service class independent of transport that serves for both SOAP and POST over HTTP. I did find that Apache CXF supports both JAX-RS and JAX-WS via single service class. Does this mean I can use the JAX-RS similar to Form posting over HTTP and JAX-WS for the SOAP. The idea is we don't want to change any of the existing consumers client code and just stream line at the provider end. Any suggestion to this regard is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I fear what you describe is a little vague. Could you please add a concrete example of what you have and what you want to do?

Comment: We have services that can be accessed via POST over HTTP and also using SOAP over HTTP. We have separate code to deal with both, we need a common framework that can support both (POST, SOAP over HTTP) using a single (business logic) code that clearly separates the transport logic from business logic. Thx.